# Pre College Mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

During my school days I was a very keen student of mathematics. But circumstances led me to opt for commerce at the college level. Now I wish to continue learning mathematics on a self study basis. First of all I would like to brush up my pre-college mathematics (which included basic algebra, number theory, euclidean geometry, basic trigonometry).

I started with the book *What is mathematics?* but found it to be too rigorous.

Can somebody recommend books which explain all *elementary concepts, proofs, theorems* in brief?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good progression/path for self-educating from pre-algebra and beyond?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87576/whats-a-good-progression-path-for-self-educating-from-pre-algebra-and-beyond)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 2):

Try this book: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamentals-University-Mathematics-Albion-Applications/dp/1898563101/ref=pd_sxp_grid_pt_0_1

It covers the topics you listed above and many more and is written in a way that's meant to prepare one for university/college study.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Precalculus (Stewart, Redlin, Watson)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0840068077). It barely touches on number theory, and abounds more in exercises than in proofs, but given your context (elementary concepts, not too rigour, self study) it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/ln.html) by William Chen cover much of the starting undergraduate curriculum in math, and are very readable.

Comment: I believe that website was torn down some time ago. Try https://www.williamchen-mathematics.info/ln.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try Math Olympiad Books, as they will be very interesting along with providing solid concepts and problems.