# Pre-College Algebra Book

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am looking for a high school/ pre-college level Algebra book that is self contained for self-study. Nothing special, I don't want a book about number theory, but a book in preparation of high school geometry, trigonometry and calculus.

I have noticed that recommendations for Algebra books on this site, start with books that are really advanced (for my level) and overshoot the mark with suggestions for abstract Algebra or number theory.

I am someone that is rebuilding my math skills and need to get a strong foundations before I move up in intellectual weight.

Comment: Search online. There are many free sites/texts. Find one that matches your level and learning style.

Comment: My guess is OP has thought of that and is trying to separate the wheat from the chaff. There is a lot of online garbage--especially at the basic level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre College Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698885/pre-college-mathematics)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free introductory resources for learning algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/free-introductory-resources-for-learning-algebra)

Answer (score 0):

J. E. Thompson's [Algebra for the Practical Man](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007DZPT6) is a classic. Another classic is the same author's [Mathematics for the Practical Man](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1495291464). These are the books Feynman learned from actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try Schaum's Outline for First Year College Math by Frank Ayres. It covers all the basic algebra/trig prep in a sympathetic manner.  Lacks geometry but really geometry is not that much a review priority for calculus.