# Books/"resources" for national math competitions.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I have started participating in math competitions an year ago. My target is to reach as far as I can in the future (USAMO and even IMO). I know that succeeding in these competitions requires a **lot** of practice (aside with talent...). I heard strong recommendations about AoPS : volume 2 and beyond as a good book for learning/practicing (I have knowledge in number theory, inductions, geometry, combinatorics...). Any way what book/"resource" do you suggest to me for preparing for these competitions (Also it is interesting for me to know which "resources" USAMO and IMO participants use)?

Comment: Of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384250/whats-a-good-book-for-a-beginner-in-high-school-math-competitions?rq=1

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2991734/32209