# Mathematics book recommendation from High school freshman level to Graduate

Tags: education, book-recommendation, advice

I am originally from India and there the mathematical curriculum was all about the formulas and not about the understanding.I used to excel at those exams,but since I have moved to Europe I have been exploring mathematics and I found out that though I might know some fairly advanced facts and formulas and my pretentious algebraic abilities can be attributed to my interest in Coding. Now here I am going to high-school but whenever I try to learn something new (btw i am 13 years old) in maths such as trigonometry,I just don't seem to like the textbooks at the local library maybe because some of the problems in them don't necessarily make it obvious to me what the application of Trig functions can be for instance.Some times even khan academy videos are a bit dumbed down(except a few).

My goal is to work my way up to Calculus (no,not because I think it sounds cool) and stuff of that level as I like physics as well.I have heard of many textbooks like the AoPS series but I am looking for textbooks with some level of difficulty and not with the huge amount of problems which are nearly identical but with different variables but those which are hard and then a detailed explanation is provided.

Bottom line,I am a guy good at Math(not some kind of prodigy by any means),but after reading some of the mind boggling work on forums such as this I feel inclined to be able to understand every word you guys are saying,so it would be awesome if you could tall me about some great textbooks,not too hard though but still gripping and with a path towards a good understanding of the topic.It would also be helpful if the textbooks can serve as a review.I want to able to go through them in an enjoyable but not slow paced manner.

Comment: Abbot: understanding analysis. (It may be too advanced, but its worth trying.)

Comment: I'd recommend baby rudins books on mathematical analysis , its a good one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbook recommendations for self-studying high school math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186555/textbook-recommendations-for-self-studying-high-school-math)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you have a look at *Basic Mathematics* by Serge Lang.

If that is below your level, or once you've finished it, I would select some books from the New Mathematical Library or the Gelfand series for high schoolers. (The books by Niven, Ore, Coxeter and Yaglom are good.)

https://www.librarything.com/series/Gelfand+Correspondence+Program+in+Mathematics

https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/anneli-lax-new-mathematical-library