# Books for highschool students to increase exposure to methods/ techniques in algebra, calculus, Coordinate Geometry

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, coordinate-systems, book-recommendation

I want to know about mathematics books for high school students which focus more towards exposure of a student to different methods or ways of solving problems in Algebra, Calculus , Coordinate Geometry. Most of the books available contain problems based on very similar types of questions or a particular method/methodology being used for the solutions (Maybe because it's the authors style or what he is used to).

I am asking this because I was reading a book by George polya "how to solve it?" in which he says

> Do you know a related problem? We can scarcely imagine a problem absolutely new, unlike and unrelated to any formerly solved problem; but, if such a problem could exist, it would be insoluble. In fact, when solving a problem, we always profit from previously solved prob-lems, using their result, or their method, or the experi-ence we acquired solving them. And, of course, the problems from which we profit must be in some way related to our present problem. Hence the question: Do you know a related problem?

And so I'm looking for a book that can increase my exposure towards topics like Algebra, Calculus and Coordinate-Geometry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbook recommendations for self-studying high school math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186555/textbook-recommendations-for-self-studying-high-school-math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources:

The [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store) books, which are intended to help students prepare for mathematics contest.

Four books authored by the great Russian mathematician I. M. Gelfand and assorted co-authors that were originally intended to supplement the Russian mathematics curriculum during the Soviet era.  They include:

[Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817636773) by I. M. Gelfand and A. Shen

[The Method of Coordinates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486425657) by I. M. Gelfand, E. G. Glagoleva, and A. A. Kirillov

[Functions and Graphs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486425649) by I. M. Gelfand, E. G. Glagoleva, and E. E. Shnol

[Trigonometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817639144) by I. M. Gelfand and M. Saul

The Japanese Fields medalist Kunihiko Kodaira edited books for Japanese high school students which contain challenging problems.  They include:

[Mathematics I: Japanese Grade 10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821805835)

[Algebra and Geometry: Japanese Grade 11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821805819)

[Basic Analysis: Japanese Grade 11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821805800)

Challenging calculus books tend to be written for college students, rather than high school students.  They include:

[Calculus: Volume I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471000051) by Tom M. Apostol

Apostol has a second volume on multi-variable calculus and linear algebra.

[Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0914098918) by Michael Spivak